# adding a shade background in running text of the middle of a paragraph

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, backgrounds

I need a background shade in the running text of middle of a paragraph, I tried through `\usepackage{tikz}`, I am getting background but text is not breaking and running beyond the text width.

How to fix automate breaking in a paragraph with shade?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\renewcommand\hl[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline,%
      decoration={amplitude=1pt,segment length=15pt},%
      outer sep=-15pt, inner sep = 0pt%
    ]%
   \node[decorate,rectangle,fill=gray!50,anchor=text]{#1};%
}%


\begin{document}

In the \hl{following chapters} of the book we a \hl{In the following chapters of the book \protect\ensuremath{\alpha \beta \gamma} we are going to be fitting statistical models to data. The script or set of R commands necessary for their analyses, data sets in CSV (comma-separated values) format, and the R workspace containing the R objects created for each chapter can be found on the companion web site. ]\hl{The R packages needed to fit the models in each chapter are indicated at the start of each chapter} and can be loaded with the specified script.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the reason for renewing the orginal `\hl` macro? If it is just for the color, you can use `\colorlet{mygray}{gray!50} \sethlcolor{mygray}`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, `\ensuremath{}` is not working, when using `\ensuremath` in the `\hl{}` command shading is turned off from that position

Answer (score 5):

The `soul` package uses a complicated algorithm for underlining and highlighting to allow for line breaking. If you replace the `\hl` macro, you essentially overwrite this sophisticated approach.

If you only want to change the color of the shading, you should use the macro `\sethlcolor` provided by the package. Note that you cannot insert modified colors like `gray!50` directly but you need to define a custom color with this value first.

Please take care that you properly set the curly brackets in your code. You can try to place stuff inside a box if it would conflict with highlighting otherwise:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{soul, xcolor}

\colorlet{mygray}{gray!50}
\sethlcolor{mygray}

\begin{document}

In the \hl{following chapters} of the book we a 
\hl{In the following chapters of the book \mbox{\protect\ensuremath{\alpha \beta \gamma}} 
we are going to be fitting statistical models to data. The script or set of R commands necessary 
for their analyses, data sets in CSV (comma-separated values) format, and the R workspace 
containing the R objects created for each chapter can be found on the companion web site.} 
\hl{The R packages needed to fit the models in each chapter are indicated at the start of 
each chapter} and can be loaded with the specified script.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: In many ways a role model for a good answer.